# Quickblox Users - Sort and filter by tags

Tags: ios, sorting, tags, quickblox

I need help with whether or not this is possible using QB Users tags. I can set up a Custom Obj class to almost achieve the below (storing values there and not in tags), but think tags would be an easier way to go about it, if possible.

Currently, it seems I cannot filter by QB User user_tags in an extended request and consequently cannot order the results by last_request_at. Also, I cannot use "or" operators for things like find all users with tag "A" or tag "B".

Is this true or am I missing something?

Ultimately, I would like to be able to find all users with tags ["A" or "D"] and ["B" or "C"] ordered by last_request_at.

Is there a best way to go about the above using QB?

Using Custom Obj, I can get a list of userIDs and then find users based on those ids by last_request_at, but then depending on the number of custom objects I retrieve, my last_request_at sort can miss some users.

Thank you again for all your work on quickblox!

Answer (score 0):

It is not achievable with current Users module.

You could get this working with CustomObjects User class.
If you have questions regarding CustomObjects please refer to [documentation](http://quickblox.com/developers/Custom_Objects) or post your questions here.

Comment: I have done this before when first learning quickblox using the custom object as an extension of users and it works well. My only hope would be that I could get users sorted by last active based on attributes in the custom object. If I retreive custom objects first and then sort users, with more users I can miss users. - think of a dating app. I want all girls who like sports and cats sorted by last request at because they r most likely to reply quickly.